# How to determine outer and inner loops of a nested list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I tried solving this practice problem from Reddit using nested comprehensions in python:

> For all the numbers 1-1000, use a nested list/dictionary comprehension
>   to find the highest single digit any of the numbers is divisible by.

The solution I came up with is :

```
div_sing_dig = {i:j for i in range(1,1001) for j in range(1,10) if i%j==0}
print(div_sing_dig)
```

When I searched for other possible solutions, I found this :

```
div_sing_dig_git = {i:max([j for j in range(1,10) if i%j==0]) for i in range(1,1001)}
print(div_sing_dig_git)
```

In the first bit of code, the first occuring for loop is the outer loop. In the second bit of code , however, the second occuring one is the outer loop.
So how do I determine outer and inner loops given a nested list comprehension ?

Comment: almost `div_sing_dig = {i:j for i in range(1,1001) for j in range(1,i) if i%j==0 }`. Just to be sure, 108's highest divisor is 54 is that what your're looking for ? The order of depth is always the order in which you write them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax or position based outer or inner loop in nested list comprehension

It all depends on how you code its logic as explained below :

e.g. your first example can be coded as either of options below :

First occuring loop as outer loop :

```
div_sing_dig = {i:j for i in range(1,1001) for j in range(1,10) if i%j==0}
print(div_sing_dig)
```

Second occuring loop as outer loop :

```
div_sing_dig2 = {j:i for i in range(1,10) for j in range(1,1001) if j%i==0}
print(div_sing_dig2)
```

Both will give same result .